# Validating input nodejs mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server

```js
login: catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const user = await pool
      .request()
      .query(
        `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='${req.body.Email}' AND Password='${req.body.Password}'`
      );
    if (!user) {
      res.status(500).json("Wrong email or password");
    }
    res.status(200).json(user.recordset);
  }),
```

Hello, I am trying to use nodejs and mssql to create a login system, when i input the correct credentials it returns the user in the database but if i input incorrect credentials, it doesn't return "wrong email or password" but returns an empty array instead. how can i return an error response if the user doesn't exists? Thanks

Comment: Though I know nothing of Node.js that looks like you're injecting your parameters, and (possibly worse) storing your passwords as plain text, rather than salted and hashed. The 2 on their own are extremely  dangerous security vulnerabilities but combined it's basically apocalyptic (for your company).

Comment: I'm new to MSSQL, i tried using bcrypt to encrypt the password but comparing the hashed password with the password entered i couldn't figure out how to go around it but with mongoDB it is straight forward to implement that